# PySpark: Count pair frequency occurences

Tags: pyspark

Let's say I have a dataset as follows:

```
1: a, b, c
2: a, d, c
3: c, d, e
```

I want to write a Pyspark code to count the occurrences of each of the pairs such as `(a,b), (a,c), (b,c)` etc.

Expected output:

```
(a,b) 1
(b,c) 1
(c,d) 2
etc..
```

Note that, `(c,d)` and `(d,c)` should be the same instant.

How should I go about it?

Till now, I have written the code to read the data from textfile as follows -

```
sc = SparkContext("local", "bp")
spark = SparkSession(sc)
data = sc.textFile('doc.txt')
dataFlatMap = data.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" "))
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide expected output.

Comment: Added the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

I relied on the answer in this question - [How to create a Pyspark Dataframe of combinations from list column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109410/how-to-create-a-pyspark-dataframe-of-combinations-from-list-column)

Below is the code that creates a udf where itertools.combinations function  is applied to the list of items. The combinations in udf  are sorted to avoid double counting occurrences such as ("a", "b") and ("b", "a"). Once you get combinations, you can groupBy and count rows. You may want to count distinct rows in case list elements are repeating, like ("a", "a", "b"), but this depends on your requirements.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import itertools
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = [(1, ["a", "b", "c"]), (2, ["a", "d", "c"]), (3, ["c", "d", "e"])]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema = ["id", "arr"])

# df is

# id   arr
# 1    ["a", "b", "c"]
# 2    ["a", "d", "c"]
# 3    ["c", "d", "e"]

@udf(returnType=ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())))
def combinations_udf(arr):
  x = (list(itertools.combinations(arr, 2)))
  return [ sorted([y[0], y[1]]) for y in x ]

df1 = (df.withColumn("combinations", F.explode(combinations_udf1("arr"))))

df_ans =(df1
          .groupBy("combinations")
          .agg(F.countDistinct("id").alias("count"))
          .orderBy(F.desc("count")))
```

For the given dataframe df, df_ans is

[image]